# Angular 6 - Is it possible to use two angular element components on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, element, angular6

I'm trying to host independent angular elements that I can drop into a non-angular webpage.  It's working great when I have just one.. but when I load two or more on the same page I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.

I'm using a build script to concatenate my dist files into one js file.. and then dropping that into my project

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const concat = require('concat')


const files = [
    './dist/elementsApp/runtime.js',
    './dist/elementsApp/polyfills.js',
    './dist/elementsApp/scripts.js',
    './dist/elementsApp/main.js',
]


fs.ensureDir('elements')
.then(() => {
  console.log('success!')
  concat(files, 'elements/include-me-somewhere-else.js')
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

I can only have one of these js files on one page.  I understand angular 7 will make this whole process easier but I'm wondering how I can accomplish this right now.

I've also tried wrapping my exported js file in a self-executing function to try and limit scope.. Doesn't fix anything unfortunately.

Any ideas?

People seem confused about what angular elements are.  For clarification you can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u9_kdkvTsc.  the last few mins in particular show an angular element being exported and included on a non angular page.  I'm trying to include multiple elements on the same page.

Comment: What is your purpose with 2 Angular app on one site?

Comment: Might be worth asking on Angular's Gitter channel. The guy who built Angular elements hangs out on there sometimes.

Comment: Are you making it so each component you want exists as it's own module?

Comment: @MichaelSolati yes i am

Comment: @hamobi I believe that's your issue then. Each import is bringing int zone.js and you're getting your issue. You should look at one module that imports the elements you want and go from there. (I could throw together a quick repo tp make this process easier. I need to do this anyway).

Comment: @MichaelSolati that's not going to work for me.  the idea is to have multiple parties working on their own projects and exporting modules as angular elements that we can add to non-angular websites.  please watch this youtube video and you can see what we're doing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u9_kdkvTsc .. the last few mins in particular.

Comment: @hamobi I see. If that's the case though I'm not sure that tutorial is the way you'll want to go. So the way that Angular Elements work is that an entire Angular app is bundled up so you have zone and everything else. I do have an idea though... I'll post an answer below (it requires a lil work).

Comment: curious for this as well, as I have to also eventually do this. Multiple angular elements on a non angular application. I succeeded to create an element and display on page as well, multiple clashing.

Comment: @hamobi any update on this ? Did you manage to come up with a solution >?

Comment: theres no way to solve this until angular 7

Answer (score 5):

I think you should not use 2 angular on one site.

Solutions can be:

- Build the whole site in Angular. Other parts of the code can be added to the app.
- Use submodules and merge the two app with a parent router.
- Use iframe for each Angular component. Then ngzone will not collide.

EDIT:

Since my original was posted there has been a technology around. Using Microfrontends (MFE) you can add more apps to the same page. In Angular it is going to be a new router element mainly. Any place where ESM `import()` can be used for lazy loading, and Angular only supports it in the Router by default.

Comment: It's two angular-elementa components. They're meant to be used as widgets outside an angular context. They're new with angular 6. They aren't angular apps in the traditional sense.

Comment: I have gotten to work by not using zones. https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef

Comment: From Angular 13 you can use microfrontend architecture. Using that you can add both of the applications to the same page and let it be loaded with some routing.

Answer (score 5):

So here's my thoughts based on our earlier discussion. Because each bundle you create with an element is loading in `zone.js` you're getting error messages:

```
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
```

What you can and should consider is NOT concatinating the `'./dist/elementsApp/polyfills.js'` into your bundle (for each element you bundle you produce). Instead use the `polyfill.js` file as a separate import into your HTML, and import it before any and all element bundles you're importing.

Comment: i will give this a shot and let you know the results

Comment: sorry for the delay.. i tried doing this and got the error "Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js"  I'm making sure to include polyfills.js before my other includes

Comment: doesn't work , it's not about how many times the polyfill is loaded, it's about the Zone itself is being constructed two times when you load two Angular elements

Answer (score 2):

Google's Polymer may be what you're looking for instead of angular:

https://www.polymer-project.org/

The Polymer library provides a set of features for creating custom elements. These features are designed to make it easier and faster to make custom elements that work like standard DOM elements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my team has already explored this.  Not quite what we're looking for.  I need a pure angular solution to including multiple angular elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that works perfectly on angular 5+. for angular 6 i have not done this.
I have done this for a huge CMS project and I inserted components in several pages and even 2 same angular module in one page. You can use one angular project.

in your site, write component tags.

You need to create another module (for example mainHelper) to export each selected angular tags.

```
import {NgModule, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
import {FirstModule} from 'YOUR MODULE PATH';
import {FirstComponent} from 'YOU COMPONENT PATH';
import {SecondModule} from 'YOUR MODULE PATH';
import {SecondComponent} from 'YOU COMPONENT PATH';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FirstModule,
    SecondModule
  ],
})

export class MainHelper {
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }
  components = [
FirstComponent,
SecondComponent
  ];


  ngDoBootstrap(ref: ApplicationRef) {
    this.components.forEach((component) => {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      const elements = document.getElementsByTagName(factory.selector); //get angular tags on your main website
      if (elements.length > 0) {
        if (elements.length > 1) {
          const selector = factory.selector;
          for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].id = selector + '-' + i;
            (<any>factory).factory.selector = '#' + elements[i].id;
            ref.bootstrap((<any>factory).factory);
            // elements[i].id = '';
          }
          (<any>factory).factory.selector = selector;
        } else {
          ref.bootstrap(component);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

in your main.ts, you can import MainHelper module and bootstrap the MainHelper.

and your FirstModule would be something like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import {FirstComponent} from './first.component';
import {AnotherComponent} from './another/another.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    SampleService // you need provide your services for all the modules
  ],
  declarations: [
    FirstComponent,
    AnotherComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [FirstComponent] // important
})
export class ECommerceModule {
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: please watch this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u9_kdkvTsc

watch the end where he exports his angular element as a concatenated javascript file and adds it to an external website.  I'm trying to include two of those files on the same page.

Comment: I see. I will do a check this weekend, however, I still prefer to do it manually sort of say. I think, the solution is, when you want to bootstrap angularElements, you need to do a bootstrap foreach one of them. I will look into it.